# Decimate modifier is reducing faces, even though the set angle is smaller than the Angle Limit set

Tags: modifiers

[image]

[image]

The decimate planar reduces the number of faces depending on the angle.
But there's a 110-degree, but at 52 degrees, the face is reduced.
Why is the face decreasing when it's less than 110 degrees?

additional question.
[image]
180-129 = 51. So I see it flattened at 52 degrees.
But I have one more question.[image]
Why is it decimated like the screen shot above?
[image]
Shouldn't the 52nd degree be straightened out?
Shouldn't it be straightened out like the red part?

[image]

It's less than 35 degrees, and it's getting decimate.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to communicate here. [Use the edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/203992/edit) to edit your question and communicate it clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English. I've revised the article and I hope the questions are clear.

Comment: I don't understand the indicated 110° but decimate planar is to say "consider planar geometry that vary less than the indicated angle, and decimate it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test case:

From left to right: 90° then 30°.

[image]

If we go above 30° in the modifier the 30° angle is decimated:

[image]

Now we have a 105° angle:

[image]

which means the angle variation is 75° (180 - 105°) following the edge (or face) variation.

So if the modifier angle goes above 75°:

[image]

... the edge collapse again.

That means the modifier is "cumulative": it will decimate all parts where the angle variation is below the given angle in the modifier.

Comment: thank you. but i have one more question. i add the question. There are times when the decimate modifier ignores several angles, why is that? I thought the face would be decimated as if it were painted in red, but it spread out like the last screenshot on top.

Comment: 148+32 makes it toggle. When it decimates, that creates a new angle that itself makes toggle the other one.

Comment: 32 degrees is straight and 145 degrees bigger, so it's below 33 degrees. Thank you! For letting me know.